# is it possible to compare environments?

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I'm trying to find a tool or a PowerShell script which allow me to compare 2 environments,
my goal is to compare my production farm and my pre prod farm and to compare as many settings as possible, including versions etc.

Answer (score 2):

They are not powershell scripts but you can try them both.

Run the tool on all your farms that you want to compare and the reports are nicely detailed.

1. http://www.spdockit.com/ -- This one comes with a price. You can try out for free.

[image]

2.http://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/ -- This one is free but not so good as the above.

You need to manually compare the reports generated from each farm.

Comment: SPSFarmReport is one of the best to compare different enviroments!

Answer (score 0):

There are few tool available in the market to do your requirement, and few are below,

1. [Compare SharePoint Farms](http://www.spdockit.com/support/help/how-to/compare-wizard/compare-sharepoint-farms/)
2. [Server Administrator for SharePoint](http://www.quest.com/server-administrator-for-sharepoint/)